# Javascript copy text without tags

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I have a script that when clicked will copy the contents of a div to the clipboard

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var program=document.getElementById('code');
ShowLMCButton(program.innerHTML, '', '', './static/js/lmcbutton.swf');
</script>
```

But when I click "Copy" it copies

```
<p>Line 1<br />Line 2</p>
```

Is there anyway to copy it like this:

Line 1
Line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) or [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The differences, according to MDN, are:

> - Note that while `textContent` gets the content of all elements,
>     including `<script>` and `<style>` elements, the mostly equivalent
>     IE-specific property, `innerText`, does not.
> - `innerText` is also aware of
>     style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas
>     `textContent` will.
> - As `innerText` is aware of CSS styling, it will
>     trigger a reflow, whereas `textContent` will not.

Comment: innerText doesn't work for me? And as for textContent, the value is strung across one line. The idea for this is to click copy and then to paste it into notepad, to share VB scripts.

Comment: `innerText` works for me (in Chrome, OSX), and it replaces the `<br>` with `\n`. `textContent` does in fact join the contents into a single line. http://jsfiddle.net/542AF/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the [innerText](http://www.yourwebskills.com/innerhtml.php) instead of innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an external library, so you should refer to the library documentation.

Anyway, there is a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).

Comment: Try this plugin, better that the flash based: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/copy